How can I properly assert multi-sorts with Shouldly?
Let's say I have a simple data class as such.
public class SortMeClass 
{
   public string StringProp { get; set; }
   public int IntProp { get; set; }
}

I then take a collection of SortMeClass objects and sort it by StringProp in ascending order, and then by IntProp in descending order.
By using Shouldly on my collection, how can I assert that it is first sorted by StringProp, and then in descending order by IntProp?

First override Equals and HashCode
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    => Equals(obj as SortMeClass);

public bool Equals(SortMeClass other)
    => other != null &&
    StringProp == other.StringProp &&
    IntProp == other.IntProp;

public override int GetHashCode()
    => HashCode.Combine(StringProp, IntProp);

Then use ShouldBe where you can explicitly control whether you care about order or not
SortMeClass[] data = 
[
    new() { StringProp = "A", IntProp = 1 },
    new() { StringProp = "A", IntProp = 2 },
    new() { StringProp = "C", IntProp = 2 },
    new() { StringProp = "B", IntProp = 2 }
];

var actual = data
   .OrderBy(x => x.StringProp)
   .ThenByDescending(x => x.IntProp);

SortMeClass[] expected = [
    new() { StringProp = "A", IntProp = 2 },
    new() { StringProp = "A", IntProp = 1 },
    new() { StringProp = "B", IntProp = 2 },
    new() { StringProp = "C", IntProp = 2 } //Change StringProp to D and see how the assertion fails
];

actual.ShouldBe(expected, ignoreOrder: false);

Dotnet fiddle link

It also works with IComparable
public class SortMeClass: IComparable 
{
    public string StringProp { get; set; }
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
    
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var other = (SortMeClass)obj;
        int stringPropCompare = this.StringProp.CompareTo(other.StringProp);
        if (stringPropCompare != 0) return stringPropCompare;
        return this.IntProp.CompareTo(other.IntProp);
    }
}

and with record as well
public record class SortMeClass 
{
    public string StringProp { get; set; }
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
}


Thanks for the answer, and this is certainly a solution.  While I was waiting for a follow-up, I opted to use a different approach that gets a List of the first sorted, string property, and then I iterate over the distinct list and check the sort of the secondary, integer column.  This works better for us because we use random data in these tests.  Anyway, even though I solved this issue myself, my hope was that I was missing a Shouldly method or, maybe, in time there will be an update where Shouldly can provide secondary sort checks.

@RLH Let's say you sort the input in your to-be-tested method via Linq. If you have access to the unsorted data inside your unit test and then you can use Sort with a custom IComparer. Then you can also use this ShouldBe approach.
